# Higher order functions in maxima

Tags: maxima

Here's a function that tries to take a function as argument, and return a function as a value.  However, when I try to apply the return value, it seems to stay unevaluated:

```
f(F) := lambda([c], F(c));
g(t) := t*t;
blah: f(g);
blah(y);
```

results in:

```
F(y)
```

`F` is the name of an argument of `f`, how is it visible outside of the definition of `f`?

I'd like

```
diff(blah(y), y):
```

to return `2*y`, but now it's just returning `d/dy F(y)`.

Comment: Take a look at this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52680489/analog-of-maple-unapply-or-mathematica-function-in-maxima/52681477#52681477 Perhaps the `evlambda` function described there can be helpful to you.